# C++ Boost - How to setup it for use in iOS and Android

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, c++11, boost

I want to use boost::serialization in my iOS / Android game (cocos2d-x game engine). I'm mainly working with Xcode and compiling for Android via a script.

I just tried to just include the whole boost folder (all headers) into my Xcode project and just run a very easy serialization sample. Though this resulted in linker errors, the linker being unable to find certain things:

```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  
> "boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::exception_code,
> char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
>       void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char,
> std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::save_impl<unsigned int>(unsigned int
> const&, mpl_::bool_<false>&) in Test.o
>       void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char,
> std::__1::char_traits<char> >
> >::save_impl<boost::archive::object_id_type>(boost::archive::object_id_type
> const&, mpl_::bool_<false>&) in Test.o
>       void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char,
> std::__1::char_traits<char> >
> >::save_impl<boost::archive::object_reference_type>(boost::archive::object_reference_type
> const&, mpl_::bool_<false>&) in Test.o
>       void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char,
> std::__1::char_traits<char> >
> >::save_impl<boost::archive::class_id_type>(boost::archive::class_id_type
> const&, mpl_::bool_<false>&) in Test.o
>       void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char,
> std::__1::char_traits<char> >
> >::save_impl<boost::archive::class_id_reference_type>
```

and so on.

The language dialect in Xcode is set to `C++11 [-std=c++11]`

Is it possible to just build the needed parts of boost from source? I believed that this would result in the smallest binary size and the least hassle, but unfortunately it's not even compiling.

For our app it's very important that including the boost library doesn't increase our binary size by much.

What do I need to do to make boost::serialization work?

Comment: to use boost serialization, you need to build the boost libraries for each target and architecture, and then link against them. do a google search for "build boost for ios". good luck.

Comment: There's no possibility for a header-only include here?

Comment: have a look at the boost serialisation documentation. It may support direct inclusion of the cpp files into your source rather than building a library.

Answer (score 1):

I have used boost for cocos2d-x and its working quite good for both iOS and android.
The easiest way to do it without increasing the binary size and without much hassle is to put the whole boost folder(the one which has all the .hpp files,subfolders) inside the following path:

> ~cocos2d-x-project-path/cocos2d/cocos/boost

Now you have to include the path of boost in Xcode like this:
Goto

> Project settings->Build Settings->Search Paths->Header Search Paths

and add the path : `$(SRCROOT)/../cocos2d/cocos/boost` like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: This is kind of what I tried, though it does not work. I want to use things like boost::serialization and it seems like it does not work with headers only. Did you have success using that?